# Exception: URL fetch failure on... when using InceptionV3

Tags: python, keras, dataset

I'm attempting to use the pre-trained InceptionV3 with keras on [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection). I have all the necessary imports:

```
import keras
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K
```

And I'm doing this to create and train the model:

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

class_names = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

CLASSES = 5
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
predictions = Dense(CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mady/Documents/EyePACSMLModelTest1.py", line 19, in <module>
    base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 28, in wrapper
    return base_fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/applications/inception_v3.py", line 11, in InceptionV3
    return inception_v3.InceptionV3(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_applications/inception_v3.py", line 390, in InceptionV3
    file_hash='bcbd6486424b2319ff4ef7d526e38f63')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 226, in get_file
    raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.5/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5: None -- [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)
```

This is my first time using the model, what does this error point to?

Thank you!